# Issue when requesting create segments API v3 through PHP wrapper

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have test-driving for Mailchimp API v3 using your PHP wrapper. It's working great for me But when I'm creating a request using POST for "Create Segment" getting an error (attach screenshot):

Request Code is (through associative array) -

```
$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us11";
$list_id = "1xx2xx3xx4xx";
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($api_key);
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/' . $list_id . '/segments', array('name' => 'Testing Data',
    'options' => array('match' => 'all',
        'conditions' => array('field' => 'type', 'op' => 'is', 'value' => 'Testing'))
        ));
```

This request call returning following error -

> array (size=2) 'field' => string 'options.conditions' (length=18)
>   'message' => string 'Schema describes array, object found instead'
>   (length=44)

[image]

I will also tried to create Request (through associative array) -

Method 1:

```
$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us11";
$list_id = "1xx2xx3xx4xx";
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($api_key);
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/' . $list_id . '/segments', array('name' => 'Testing Data',
    'options' => array('match' => 'all',
        'conditions' => array(array('field' => 'type', 'op' => 'is', 'value' => 'Testing')))
        ));
```

Method 2:

```
$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us11";
$list_id = "1xx2xx3xx4xx";
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($api_key);
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/' . $list_id . '/segments', array('name' => 'Testing Data 4',
    'options' => array('match' => 'all',
        'conditions' => array(array('field' => 'type'), array('op' => 'is'), array('value' => 'Testing')))
        ));
```

Both method will create segment on mailchimp account but not have any conditions. See screenshot -

[image]

How to override this problem?

Comment: May you try to name the last array in your _Method 1_ based on your Segemnet Type, i.e. like this: `"conditions"=>array("EmailAddress"=>array("op"=>"foo", ... ))`, check out the docs -> https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/.

Comment: @Andy: thanks, but it's didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry. May you try to work round to achieve the expected result. Try to simply put a value into the array, then another array or an object, just every combination which comes in your mind and try to get content in the `conditions`-Array

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the condition_type param. It should be selected from the list provided by MailChimp in the endpoint documentation.
For example, IF the field "type" from your MailChimp list is a text field you should use `'condition_type': 'TextMerge'`. In this case, conditions should have the following format:

```
[
    {
        'condition_type': 'TextMerge',
        'field': 'type',
        'op': 'is',
        'value': 'Testing'
    }
]
```

However, MailChimp MAY have a bug in this endpoint, since TextMerge works only on the EMAIL field. I have also stumbled upon this problem recently:

[Mailchimp api v3 - can't create segment based on a TEXT merge field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635932/mailchimp-api-v3-cant-create-segment-based-on-a-text-merge-field)

https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/issues/160