# Mailchimp api v3 - can't create segment based on a TEXT merge field

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0, segments

I'm trying to create a segment based on a new merge field of type TEXT that I just created, by using condition_type = TextMerge since it seems to be the only option from their documentation that matches my field:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/#create-post_lists_list_id_segments

However, the description for TextMerge looks identical to EmailAddress. To be more specific they both apply only for the EMAIL / MERGE0 field.

[TextMerge vs EmailAddress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNqJ.png)

I tried the following combinations for 'conditions':

```
{
    'condition_type': 'TextMerge',
    'field': 'EVENTS',
    'op': 'contains',
    'value': 'test'
}
```

and

```
{
    'condition_type': 'TextMerge',
    'field': 'EMAIL',
    'op': 'contains',
    'value': 'test'
}
```

The first one returns an error:

```
{
    "type":"http:\/\/developer.mailchimp.com\/documentation\/mailchimp\/guides\/error-glossary\/",
    "title":"Invalid Resource",
    "status":400,
    "detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
    "instance":"",
    "errors":
    [
        {
            "field":"options.conditions.item:0",
            "message":"Data did not match any of the schemas described in anyOf."
        }
    ]
}
```

The second one works.

My question is: how can I create a segment based on a custom merge field of type TEXT? To me this looks like a bug from their side. Did anyone else have this problem? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you add the complete error response? It should be a json with `errors` as an array.

Comment: Yes, I added it, but it doesn't contain any relevant information.

Comment: The only way I can get the exact same response as you is if `condition_type` or `op` has an invalid value, or both `condition_type` and `op` have invalid values. For example `condition_type` is `TextMerge2` or `op` is `contains2`. Based on your `conditions` parameter, looks like this is the problem: `'op: 'contains'`, are you sure it's not a typo? It should be `'op': 'contains'` (notice the quote after `op`).

Comment: :) I manually wrote that in here. No typos in the code. As I said, if I change the field to EMAIL it works. Did you successfully create a segment based on a text field?

Comment: Yes I actually did using c#. What technology are you using to make the request? curl, php, c#, python, or something else?

Comment: I envy you. I'm using PHP.

Comment: You should add your php code to your question and add [php] tag so hopefully other people with php skills could help. If you're using some kind of php wrapper, then it's possible that the wrapper messes the request body somehow since I could successfully create the segment using c#. You could also contact MailChimp support team, just to make sure that this is not a bug from their end.

Comment: Will do. Thank you. I already posted a question to the MC team.

Comment: @GabrielaRaducan Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @AlxVallejo , no. I had to find another solution for my problem because MC team never answered and the bug was never fixed.. or at least not while I was working on that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my issue specific to `TEXT` fields in my mailchimp audience merge tags.

Apparently, when adding a `TEXT` field, it defaults to a maximum size of 25 characters. I was trying to put more text than that into it. It fails with the error:

```rb
@body={
  "title"=>"Invalid Resource",
  "status"=>400,
  "detail"=>"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
  "errors"=>[{"field"=>"merge_fields.MMERGE_16",
  "message"=>"Data did not match any of the schemas described in anyOf."}]
}
```

I increased the field size to 255 via Mailchimp's API.